# Refactoring List abstraction - C

Tags: design, c, coding-style, refactoring, interfaces

Below is the working `List` abstraction design,

[image]

---

`List` is a generic abstraction holding any type.

Below is the code directory structure. Currently symbol table(`ST`) and file api `fileIO` is using `List` abstraction.

```
./Code$
.:
fileIO  list  ST tinyTale type.h frequencyCounter.c frequencyCounter.exe

./fileIO:
file.h  fileReading.c

./list:
arrayImpl.c   config.c virtualImplLayer.c linkedListImpl.c  list.h listHandler.h  listInterface.h  

./ST:
implWithArray.c  ST.h
```

---

Below is the relevant code(for improvement),

## list.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H /* Header guard */
#define LIST_H
#include"type.h"

  typedef struct List List;


 typedef int (*compareTo)(const void *, const void *);
 typedef bool (*isLess)(const void *, const void *);
 typedef bool (*isEqual)(const void *, const void *);

#endif
```

---

## listHandler.h

```
/***********listHandler.h ***********/
#ifndef LISTHANDLER_H
#define LISTHANDLER_H

#include"list/list.h"
typedef struct {

         bool(*canHandle)(char*);
        List*(*createList)(void);
         void(*freeList)(List*);
         void(*swim)(List*, int, isLess);
         void(*sink)(List*, int, isLess);
        void*(*listDeleteMaxElement)(List*, isLess);
        void*(*sortedListDeleteMaxElement)(List*);
          int(*listGetSize)(List*);
  const void*(*listGetItem)(List*, const int);
        List*(*sortedListInsertItem)(List*, void*, compareTo);
         void(*listInsertItem)(List*, void*);
        void*(*listDeleteItem)(List*, int);
        void*(*listDeleteLastItem)(List*);
        void*(*listDeleteFirstItem)(List*);
         int(*linearSearch)(const void*, List*, size_t, compareTo);
        void*(*binarySearch)(const void*, List*, size_t, compareTo);
         void(*insertionSort)(List*, size_t, isLess);
         void(*mergeSort)(List*, size_t, isLess);
         void(*swap)(List*, int, int);

}ListHandler;

/*
  "config.c" lookup below 2 global symbols created in impl handlers,
   before linking time, so "extern" keyword
*/
extern ListHandler arrayImplHandler;
extern ListHandler linkedListImplHandler;

/*
  "viml.c" lookup below global symbol created in "config.c",
   before linking time, so "extern" keyword
*/
extern ListHandler *listHandlers[];

/* Prototypes for definitions in viml.c - start ********/
        List* vCreateList(char *);
         void vFreeList(List*, char *);
         void vSwim(List*, int, isLess, char *);
         void vSink(List*, int, isLess, char *);
        void* vListDeleteMaxElement(List*, isLess, char *);
        void* vSortedListDeleteMaxElement(List*, char *);
          int vListGetSize(List*, char *);
  const void* vListGetItem(List*, const int, char *);
        List* vSortedListInsertItem(List*, void*, compareTo, char *);
         void vListInsertItem(List*, void*, char *);
        void* vListDeleteItem(List*, int, char *);
        void* vListDeleteLastItem(List*, char *);
        void* vListDeleteFirstItem(List*, char *);
          int vLinearSearch(const void*, List*, size_t, compareTo, char *);
        void* vBinarySearch(const void*, List*, size_t, compareTo, char *);
         void vInsertionSort(List*, size_t, isLess, char *);
         void vMergeSort(List*, size_t, isLess, char *);
         void vSwap(List*, int, int, char *);
/*****End ***********************************************/

#endif
```

---

## listInterface.h

```
#include"list/listHandler.h"

#ifndef LISTINTERFACE_H
#define LISTINTERFACE_H

/*********** User Interface - start *****************/
#define createList()                   vCreateList(argv[1])
#define freeList(a)                    vFreeList(a, argv[1])
#define swim(a, b, c)                  vSwim(a, b, c, argv[1])
#define sink(a, b, c)                  vSink(a, b, c, argv[1])
#define deleteMax(a, b)                vListDeleteMaxElement(a, b, argv[1])
#define sortDeleteMax(a)               vSortedListDeleteMaxElement(a, argv[1])
#define getSize(a)                     vListGetSize(a, argv[1])
#define getItem(a, b)                  vListGetItem(a, b, argv[1])
#define sortInsertItem(a, b, c)        vSortedListInsertItem(a, argv[1])
#define insertItem(a, b)               vListInsertItem(a, b, argv[1])
#define deleteItem(a, b)               vListDeleteItem(a, b, argv[1])
#define deleteLastItem(a)              vListDeleteLastItem(a, argv[1])
#define deleteFirstItem(a)             vListDeleteFirstItem(a, argv[1])
#define lSearch(a, b, c, d)            vLinearSearch(a, b, c, d, argv[1])
#define bSearch(a, b ,c, d)            vBinarySearch(a, b, c, d, argv[1])
#define callInsertionSort(a, b, c)     vInsertionSort(a, b, c, argv[1])
#define callMergeSort(a, b, c)         vMergeSort(a, b, c, argv[1])
#define swap(a, b, c)                  vSwap(a, b, c, argv[1])

/*********** User Interface - end *****************/
#endif
```

---

where, `listInterface.h` is an interface for a user of `List` abstraction.

All api wth prefix(`v`) are defined in `virtualImplLayer.c`.

But,

1)

`listInterface.h` is not a readable code for user, because it does not possess `List` *typedef* which is actually available in `list.h` and indirectly included via `listHandler.h`.

2)
`listInterface.h` is not easy to use because user(say `fileReading.c`) need to pass `argv` argument to `List` public api. Public api is given in `listInterface.h`. User has to run its application passing `argv[1]` as,

`$ ./userapp.exe ARRAY`

or

`$ ./userapp.exe LINKEDLIST`

Question:

Can `listInterface.h` get more readable & easy to use?

Comment: How important is it that the end-user can select the implementation of the list abstraction? What would you do if the intended end-user doesn't even know what that means?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau **##1)** If the end user need list container for his applications then it is important to select the `List` abstraction. **##2)** I would convey the user with documentation. Like java does [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). But despite documentation, I feel `listInterface.h` is a nightmare for user.

Comment: I used the term 'end-user' to refer to the person who uses the final application, not the person writing that application. If that application is an e-mail client, then the end-user could be your mother wanting to read her mail. Do you want to bother *them* with the choice between a linked-list or array implementation?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau You are right!! But any one implementation(array or linkedlist) has to be picked at run time. What is the approach?

Comment: Why does it have to be picked at run time? Why can't the application developer choose which to use when building/compiling the application?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I implemented  [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150452/stack-abstraction) that picks at compile time as mentioned in compilation procedure. Disadvantage is lot of conditional compiltations

Comment: Why are conditional compilations a disadvantage, and what makes reinventing C++'s vtable wheel an advantage?

Comment: @Birfl Replied for your comment in below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to make `listInterface.h` easier to use. One of the easiest ways is to combine `list.h` and `listInterface.h` into one file and to move the declarations of the vXXX functions there as well.

As a second refactoring, you should remove the implementation selector ("ARRAY" or "LINKEDLIST" string) from all interface functions. 
If you want to have run-time selection of the implementation, then you should either have a single function to select the implementation to use for the whole program, or you should specify it only on the `createList` function as an explicit argument.
That way, users of the list abstraction can't accidentally create a linked list and then call the array implementation on it.
Having the argument explicitly, and not implicitly as `argv[1]`, makes it clear that there is a choice here and gives the possibility to base the choice on something else than the first program argument.

Comment: How `socket()` calls makes you pick `AF_INET` family implementation by passing `AF_INET` as first argument to `socket()` api? Do you see the analogy?

Comment: `static const struct net_proto_family __rcu *net_families[NPROTO] __read_mostly;int sock_register(const struct net_proto_family *ops){..}`  If I see this code in `socket.c`, I think `sock_register()` gets called when `af_inet`/`af_unix`/any family `.so` file is loaded in memory. For example, `(void)sock_register(&inet_family_ops);` is being called from `af_inet.c` by overriding `_init()` runtime code. Have a look at it

Comment: This code is the inspiration of writing `List` abstraction which is yet to reach in next design by overriding `_init()` in `arrayImpl.so` and `linkedListImpl.so` going further. Currently, my code has implementations(`ListHandler`) connected at link time unlike `sock_register()` that is called at load time of `af_inet` library(`.so`)

Comment: @overexchange: I see the intended analogy with sockets. Do you also see that you only have to specify `AF_INET` once when creating a socket and not over and over again when using the socket? That would correspond to specifying the List implementation only when creating a new list.